# Docker is creating random container

Tags: docker

I recently installed Docker on my Raspberry Pi 4 and connected it to a portrainer instance on my other server. On my Raspberry Pi I created two docker containers, but somehow docker automatically creates random ubuntu containers with names like:

I don't have an idea why it is doing this: /

[image: Portrainer Screenshot of Containers]

But when I delete those Containers, a few hours later there are some other containers again.

I hope anyone can help me with that kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i think i solved this question...

I run this webinterface (Portrainer) on my public hosted server. And i only shared my ip with my port for Portrainer as "Endpoint" and now i have disabled the port on my raspberry for all other IPs then my Raspberry PI. And now i solved this problem. No container is created anymore. I came up to this solution, because i saw the infos, this container was created and it "wgets" some ".sh"-file from some ip with executing some shell commands. And i thought, "this is not from mine, this is someone want to mine some bitcoins on my raspberry". (because this script downloaded some mining scripts.....

:PS: My english is very bad. But i hope it helped someone other.

Answer (score 0):

Those random names are created automatically when a container is started without a name attribute. If you did not start an unnamed container yourself (by issuing `docker run` without the `--name` option), those are most likely being created by a `docker build`.

You can delete those stopped containers manually one at a time or use commands like `docker system prune` (see `docker help system prune` for documentation) to cleanup your daemon from unused objects (including those stopped containers).

Comment: No i didn't started a container without a name option. These containers are created by themself. So if i dont touch anything there are 20 other containers tomorrow.

Comment: And you are not building any images either ?

Comment: What do you mean with "building any images"?

Comment: I mean do you use `docker build` or does your tool we see on the GUI screenshot do it ?

Comment: I'm a beginner in Docker, but don't think so. I just used docker commit to create an image from one running container. Portrainer only pulled these images from DockerHub and run them as Container. And i (portrainer) have recently pulled a ubuntu image and ran it. And since them this is happening.